# High RPM CVT for Spindle Motor

Tags: motors, cnc, power-transmission

I have been messing about with a 20k RPM spindle motor and want to try to have some more low end torque. I was thinking about using a belt or chain CVT so I can smoothly change gear ratios but is there any issues with using a CVT at those kinds of RPMs?

If I can find good enough bearings the idea of having a high end option of 40k rpm is appealing if the CVT can handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Belt drives as used in CVT systems (snowmobiles, for example) generally have operating limits placed on their *linear speed* (in feet per second) by the belt manufacturer. Knowing what that will be for your application then lets you search for a belt that will work.

For dividing down the speed of a shaft running at 20,000 RPM or more, specially-designed gear drives are commonly used. You would be better off first gearing down the spindle to get a more manageable RPM setpoint and connecting that reduction drive to a belt-style CVT.